# SQL Server - Update Column with Handing Duplicate and Unique Rows Based Upon Timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, ssis

I'm working with SQL Server 2005 and looking to export some data off of a table I have. However, prior to do that I need to update a status column based upon a field called "VisitNumber", which can contain multiple entries same value entries. I have a table set up in the following manner. There are more columns to it, but I am just putting in what's relevant to my issue

```
ID  Name       MyReport  VisitNumber  DateTimeStamp            Status
--  ---------  --------  -----------  -----------------------  ------
1   Test John  Test123   123          2014-01-01 05.00.00.000
2   Test John  Test456   123          2014-01-01 07.00.00.000
3   Test Sue   Test123   555          2014-01-02 08.00.00.000
4   Test Ann   Test123   888          2014-01-02 09.00.00.000
5   Test Ann   Test456   888          2014-01-02 10.00.00.000
6   Test Ann   Test789   888          2014-01-02 11.00.00.000
```

**Field Notes**

- ID column is a unique ID in incremental numbers
- MyReport is a text value and can actually be thousands of characters. Shortened for simplicity. In my scenario the text would be completely different
- Rest of fields are varchar

**My Goal**

I need to address putting in a status of "F" for two conditions:
* If there is only one VisitNumber, update the status column of "F"
* If there is more than one visit number, only put "F" for the one based upon the earliest timestamp. For the other ones, put in a status of "A"

So going back to my table, here is the expectation

```
ID  Name       MyReport  VisitNumber  DateTimeStamp            Status
--  ---------  --------  -----------  -----------------------  ------
1   Test John  Test123   123          2014-01-01 05.00.00.000  F
2   Test John  Test456   123          2014-01-01 07.00.00.000  A
3   Test Sue   Test123   555          2014-01-02 08.00.00.000  F
4   Test Ann   Test123   888          2014-01-02 09.00.00.000  F
5   Test Ann   Test456   888          2014-01-02 10.00.00.000  A
6   Test Ann   Test789   888          2014-01-02 11.00.00.000  A
```

I was thinking I could handle this by splitting each types of duplicates/triplicates+ (2,3,4,5). Then updating every other (or every 3,4,5 rows). Then delete those from the original table and combine them together to export the data in SSIS. But I am thinking there is a much more efficient way of handling it.

Any thoughts? I can accomplish this by updating the table directly in SQL for this status column and then export normally through SSIS. Or if there is some way I can manipulate the column for the exact conditions I need, I can do it all in SSIS. I am just not sure how to proceed with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY VisitNumber ORDER BY DateTimeStamp) rn from MyTable
)

UPDATE cte
SET [status] = (CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'F' ELSE 'A' END)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kapol, this worked perfectly. I also learned more about Common Table Expressions. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I put together a test script to check the results. For your purposes, use the update statements and replace the temp table with your table name.

```
            create table #temp1 (id int, [name] varchar(50), myreport varchar(50), visitnumber varchar(50), dts datetime, [status] varchar(1))

    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (1,'Test John','Test123','123','2014-01-01 05:00')
    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (2,'Test John','Test456','123','2014-01-01 07:00')
    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (3,'Test Sue','Test123','555','2014-01-01 08:00')
    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (4,'Test Ann','Test123','888','2014-01-01 09:00')
    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (5,'Test Ann','Test456','888','2014-01-01 10:00')
    insert into #temp1 (id,[name],myreport,visitnumber, dts) values (6,'Test Ann','Test789','888','2014-01-01 11:00')

    select * from #temp1;

    update #temp1 set status = 'F'
    where id in (
    select id from #temp1 t1
    join (select min(dts) as mindts, visitnumber
            from #temp1
            group by visitNumber) t2
    on t1.visitnumber = t2.visitnumber
    and t1.dts = t2.mindts)

    update #temp1 set status = 'A'

    where id not in (
    select id from #temp1 t1
    join (select min(dts) as mindts, visitnumber
            from #temp1
            group by visitNumber) t2
    on t1.visitnumber = t2.visitnumber
    and t1.dts = t2.mindts)

    select * from #temp1;
    drop table #temp1
```

Hope this helps